# line don't break with \n angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem when i do this :

```
DetailDisplayer(row) : String {
    let resultAsString = "";
    console.log(row.metadata.questions.length);
    (row.metadata.questions.length != 0 )?resultAsString += "Questions :" + row.metadata.questions.join("\n") + "\n" : resultAsString += "Questions : " + "No questions" + "\n";
    (row.metadata.startDate)?resultAsString += "Start date  : " + row.metadata.startDate + "\n" : resultAsString += "Start date : " + "No date" + "\n";
    (row.metadata.endDate)?resultAsString += "End date : " + row.metadata.endDate + "\n" : resultAsString += "Date de fin : " + "Aucune date" + "\n";
    console.log(resultAsString);
    return resultAsString;
  }
```

(by default, all of these tests are false)

my output on my html is

`Questions : No questions Start date : No date End date : No date`

With this html code :

```html
<ngx-datatable-row-detail rowHeight="auto" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
        <div style="padding-left:35px;">
            <div><strong>DETAILS</strong></div>
            <div>{{ DetailDisplayer(row) }}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

I'm using row details function of the ngx datatable Angular component.
console.log(resultAsString); displayed me what i wish :

```
Questions : No questions 
Start date : No date 
End date : No date
```

So i don't understand why there is no break line displayed on my app. If somebody can help me to understand, thank you by advanced.

Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the style `white-space: pre;` to div with `DetailDisplayer`. Try this:

```
<ngx-datatable-row-detail rowHeight="auto" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
        <div style="padding-left:35px;">
            <div><strong>DETAILS</strong></div>
            <div style="white-space: pre">{{ DetailDisplayer(row) }}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the CSS property/value to your element `white-space: pre-line;`.

Most HTML elements will not display \n as a new-line by default.